# Simple cube and square sum function won't run (C)

Tags: c, input

Learning C, trying to code a program that outputs the sum of the cube and square of an inputted number.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
int a;
scanf("%d",a);
printf("%d",cube(a)+sqr(a));
}

cube(int x)
{
return(x*x*x);
}

sqr(int arg)
{
return(arg*arg);
}
```

When I run the program it outputs some seemingly random string of numbers after I input a number. Any way to fix it without changing the usage of returns to assign variables?

Comment: write &a in your scanf statement

Comment: always compile you code as: `gcc -Wall -pedantic  code.c -c exe`

Comment: someone want to explain to me what that is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`scanf` needs a pointer:

```
scanf("%d",&a);
```

instead of

```
scanf("%d",a);
```

Comment: Thanks lol was such a simple mistake

Comment: Your compiler should have warned you about this one. Are you compiling with ``-Wall`` (gcc/linux) ?

Comment: don't know what that means.. I'm using codeblocks and it ran the program but crashed after input

Comment: In "project -> Build options ->  Compiler settings -> Compiler flags" you should check "enable all compiler warnings" and pay attention to those warnings.

Answer (score 4):

```
int a;
scanf("%d",a);

          ^
```

must be `&a`. `d` conversion specifier for `scanf` expects a pointer to `int` argument.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a return type to your functions !

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int a;
  scanf("%d",a);
  printf("%d",cube(a)+sqr(a));
  return 0;
}

int cube(int x)
{
  return(x*x*x);
}

int sqr(int arg)
{
  return(arg*arg);
}
```

Comment: Actually it looks like he's using an old compiler which supports implicit int return types.

Comment: Tried your code and it has the same problem. I believe in C, int is implied if the return type isn't specified.

Comment: @PaulR I didn't know about this, my bad sry x)

Comment: No problem - this kind of C usage is about 20 - 30 years out of date !

Comment: NP the solution was posted anyways thanks for trying!

Answer (score 0):

You have not given address of "a" in scanf function.

Please use:

```
scanf("%d", &a);
```

Comment: `&a` is not the address of `a`. The address will be hexadecimal. `&a` just gives the address of `a` to `scanf`.